# How to get the current locale in Flutter using the GetX package?

Tags: flutter, get, internationalization

The example  https://pub.dev/packages/get/example  only shows setting the locale from a string manually:

```
void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
    ...
    locale: Locale('pt', 'BR'),
    ...
```

If I don't use "locale: Locale ('pt', 'BR')", then code like Text("title".tr) don't work.
So, I need setup current locale to "locale" property, but how get current locale?

Answer (score 21):

if BuildContext is available, we can get current locale this way

```dart
Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
```

according to the documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

another option is to use the official intl library

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String locale = Intl.getCurrentLocale(); // returns language tag, such as en_US
```

Answer (score 12):

To get Device Current Locale:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

return GetMaterialApp(
     locale: Get.deviceLocale,   //returns Locale('<language code>', '<country code>')
);
```

To get the App Current Locale:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

return GetMaterialApp(
     locale: Get.locale,   //returns Locale('<language code>', '<country code>')
);
```

[GetX | Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/get#locales)

[Sample Code](https://github.com/zeeshanayaz/getx_multi_language_flutter)

Answer (score 5):

if u need device locale, u can use

```
return GetMaterialApp(
     locale: Get.deviceLocale,
);
```

but u need current app locale u must be use

```
final locale = Get.locale;
```

Answer (score 4):

The authors of the package added information about this in Readme (https://pub.dev/packages/get#internationalization):

To read the system locale, you could use window.locale.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

return GetMaterialApp(
    locale: ui.window.locale,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Get.locale` read only property defined inside the `LocalesIntl` extension from `package:get/get_utils/src/extensions/internacionalization.dart`

```
final locale = Get.locale;
```

If you want current system locale, `window.locale` and add `import 'dart:ui';`

Answer (score 1):

```
return GetMaterialApp(
    locale: Get.deviceLocale,
);
```